# How to do an inner join by row number using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Two tables:

Table A has following data:

```
Type1 A
Type1 B
Type1 C
Type1 D
```

Table B has following data:

```
Type2 X
Type2 Y
Type2 U
Type2 V
```

I want to get the following output:

```
new { A, X }
new { B, Y }
new { C, U }
new { D, V }
```

Is this possible using Entity Framework? The problem I am facing now is there're 8 different entity tables, each represent a type. The app has an index page, we want to show 6 items of each table on the index page. We can do this one by one of course, but that will hit the DB 8 times, which may not be very efficient. What's the right way to solve such a problem using EF 6?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var AX = db.tableA 
.Join( 
tableB, 
foo1 => foo1.A, 
foo2 => foo2.X, 
(foo1, foo2) => new { foo1, foo2}
.ToList()



var BY = db.tableA 
    .Join( 
    tableB, 
    foo1 => foo1.B, 
    foo2 => foo2.Y, 
    (foo1, foo2) => new { foo1, foo2}
    .ToList()

  var CU = db.tableA 
    .Join( 
    tableB, 
    foo1 => foo1.C, 
    foo2 => foo2.U, 
    (foo1, foo2) => new { foo1, foo2}
    .ToList()

  var DV = db.tableA 
    .Join( 
    tableB, 
    foo1 => foo1.D, 
    foo2 => foo2.V, 
    (foo1, foo2) => new { foo1, foo2}
    .ToList()
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. First, every ToList() will be translated to a sql query, as I said in the question that's what I want to avoid. Second, join without a on condition will be translate to a full cross join, which will be a cartesian product, not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use *EF*, probably all your tables have `int` *PK* with identity. If you also have never deleted separated rows, located between others, from these tables, you can use *Id* columns for join condition. You can simple extend this example to desired number of tables with same manner.

```
var tableA = from itemA in ctx.tableA
             let minId = ctx.tableA.Min(x => x.Id)
             select new { itemA, index = itemA.Id - minId };

var tableB = from itemB in ctx.tableB 
             let minId = ctx.tableB.Min(x => x.Id)
             select new { itemB, index = itemB.Id - minId };

var answer = (from itemAA in tableA
              join itemBB in tableB on itemAA.index equals itemBB.index
              select new { itemAA.itemA, itemBB.itemB}).ToList().SelectMany(x => {
                  var result = new List<Tuple<Type1, Type2>>();
                  var props1 = x.itemA.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
                  var props2 = x.itemB.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
                  for(var i = 0; i < Math.Min(props1.Count, props2.Count); i++)                              
                       result.Add(new Tuple<Type1, Type2>((Type1)props1[i].GetValue(x.itemA), (Type2)props2[i].GetValue(x.itemB)));
                   return result;                                  
              }).ToList();
```